# Is it possible to rewrite URL with parameter?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have this URL `example.com/photo?people`

I want to rewrite this URL in the form : `example.com/photo/people`

Is it possible ?

Comment: What's your real example url? `?people` is more likely to be a key/value like `?people=something` or `?something=people`

Comment: `example.com/photo?people` and `example.com/photo?people=Steffi`

Comment: so what is the rewritten url to look like for people=Steffi?

Comment: `example.com/photo/people/steffi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^photo/(\w+)$ /photo?$1
```

Comment: And what if my url is : `example.com?people` and I want `example.com/people` ?

Comment: @Steffi I guess you have to define the structure you want first, but that would be: `RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /$1`.

Comment: The rewrite URL `http://www.example.com/2011/photo/people` for `http://www.example.com/2011/photo?people` doesn't work with `RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /$1`

Comment: @Steffi No it doesn't. Like I said, you will have to define your url structure first.

Comment: @Steffi For example, if the first section would be a number, then a type and then a section, you could do `RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\w+)/(\w+)$ /?year=$1&type=$2&section=$3`